# Unable to add a new user to the sudo group

Tags: sudo, freebsd, users

In Ubuntu I can do this in order to add a new group and user:

```
groupadd group123
useradd -m -s /bin/bash -g group123 user123
usermod -a -G sudo,www-data user123
```

I was able to do this in FreeBsd:

```
sudo pw groupadd group123
sudo pw useradd user123 -m -s /bin/tcsh -g group123
```

But this has failed:

```
sudo pw usermod -a -G sudo,www-data user123
```

because the group sudo didn't exist. Why not? doesn't "sudo pw" imply that it must? If not, how to properly add it?

Comment: the sudo group doesn't have to exist, no. it's a convenience for entering sudo rules. Does your sudoers file refer to %sudo for rules?

Comment: FreeBSD has a great documentation which covers this: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/users-synopsis.html

Comment: @JeffSchaller, how to find out that?

Comment: @val0x00ff, hence, how to fix it?

Comment: `grep %sudo /etc/sudoers`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, nothing

Comment: Then IMHO you're solving the wrong problem. Your sudoers file is granting privileges based on something else. Adding a sudo group probably won't solve this particular problem.

Comment: @Dorion you first need to verify if the group exists. Check this using `grep 'sudo' /etc/passwd` If sudo group exists then use  `sudo pw groupmod sudo -m user123`  This will only succeed if the `sudo` group exists

Comment: @val0x00ff, I've added a user to the group "wheel" instead.

Answer (score 6):

There is no default group named "sudo" on FreeBSD. There is no connection between the command "sudo" and the presence of a group named "sudo".

You can see which groups you have on your system using:

```
$ cat /etc/group
```

It is common on many Linux distributions (including Ubuntu) to have a group named "sudo". On FreeBSD it is most common to use the groups "wheel" or "operators" for the same purpose.

The `sudo` program reads a configuration file. This file determines which users and groups are allowed to do what.

If sudo was installed with the `pkg` package installer then you find the sudo configuration file here:

```
/usr/local/etc/sudoers
```

The interesting part of the configuration file are the following lines:

```
## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

## Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to execute any command
# %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

My guess is that someone set your system up to allow sudo for the group "wheel" and added your user to that group. The group "sudo" does simply not exist and you cannot add anyone to a non-existing group.

You should either add the user to the "wheel" group (or whatever defined in `/usr/local/etc/sudoers`) - or you should create the group "sudo" and make sure it is not commented out in `/usr/local/etc/sudoers`

Further reading in section [13.14. Shared Administration with Sudo](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/security-sudo.html) in the FreeBSD Handbook. The man pages for the command [sudo](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sudo) and the [configuration file](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sudoers) for the full monty.